# purposes of transactions

Tags: c#, transactions

I read so much articles about this subject and I still got some important and basic questions.
what is the purpose of transactions if it isnt use for SQL? how does it help me in wcf?
This article show an example of using simple transactions:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(v=vs.90).aspx

what is the purpose of this code below if it isn't for rolling back what ever they trying to restore in case the code fail?

```
    void RootMethod()
{
     using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
     {
          /* Perform transactional work here */
          SomeMethod();
          scope.Complete();
     }
}

void SomeMethod()
{
     using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
     {
          /* Perform transactional work here */
          scope.Complete();
     }
}
```

Comment: Same as transactions are anywhere else, i imagine.   Either everything happens, or nothing does.

Comment: I have removed the last question. Please only ask one question at the same time.

Comment: @cHao, not true. Only resources supporting transaction participate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only resources supporting transactions participate in a transaction. Usually, this is only SQL Server. Message Queueing also supports transactions.

If you don't use any transaction-enabled resource (like normal variables...) this won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good example here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope(v=vs.90).aspx#Y500

In the example (link above, code below) the SQL connection objects will automatically participate in the transaction -- thus these SQL commands won't commit before the transaction is complete (`scope.Complete`).  In this way both will happen on two separate servers only if the other happened.  Any exception will cause both to rollback.

Your example is not clear because it is only in the context of that page to describe nested scopes.  The example is showing something that WOULD be considered nested, not some code that would do anything useful.

Here is microsoft's example code which I think is quite clear:

```
// This function takes arguments for 2 connection strings and commands to create a transaction 
// involving two SQL Servers. It returns a value > 0 if the transaction is committed, 0 if the 
// transaction is rolled back. To test this code, you can connect to two different databases 
// on the same server by altering the connection string, or to another 3rd party RDBMS by 
// altering the code in the connection2 code block.
static public int CreateTransactionScope(
    string connectString1, string connectString2,
    string commandText1, string commandText2)
{
    // Initialize the return value to zero and create a StringWriter to display results.
    int returnValue = 0;
    System.IO.StringWriter writer = new System.IO.StringWriter();

    try
    {
        // Create the TransactionScope to execute the commands, guaranteeing
        // that both commands can commit or roll back as a single unit of work.
        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectString1))
            {
                // Opening the connection automatically enlists it in the 
                // TransactionScope as a lightweight transaction.
                connection1.Open();

                // Create the SqlCommand object and execute the first command.
                SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand(commandText1, connection1);
                returnValue = command1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command1: {0}", returnValue);

                // If you get here, this means that command1 succeeded. By nesting
                // the using block for connection2 inside that of connection1, you
                // conserve server and network resources as connection2 is opened
                // only when there is a chance that the transaction can commit.   
                using (SqlConnection connection2 = new SqlConnection(connectString2))
                {
                    // The transaction is escalated to a full distributed
                    // transaction when connection2 is opened.
                    connection2.Open();

                    // Execute the second command in the second database.
                    returnValue = 0;
                    SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand(commandText2, connection2);
                    returnValue = command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    writer.WriteLine("Rows to be affected by command2: {0}", returnValue);
                }
            }

            // The Complete method commits the transaction. If an exception has been thrown,
            // Complete is not  called and the transaction is rolled back.
            scope.Complete();

        }

    }
    catch (TransactionAbortedException ex)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("TransactionAbortedException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
    }
    catch (ApplicationException ex)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("ApplicationException Message: {0}", ex.Message);
    }

    // Display messages.
    Console.WriteLine(writer.ToString());

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: Why in the example above, the latter Connection,Connection2, is initialize inside of Connection1's initialization? Is it important or can be done out side Connection1's initialization?

Comment: It is right there in the comments -- you save resources because you only need to open connection2 if connection1 can connect and worked -- otherwise you will end up rolling back anyway.  READ THE COMMENTS